# Django model class method for todays average and latest record

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a class in my django models as below:

```
class Meter(models.Model):
    rec_time = models.DateTimeField(primary_key=True)
    energy = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=3)
    power = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    @classmethod
    def daily_summary(date_rec=date.today()):
        res = Meter.objects.filter(rec_time__date=date_rec)
        res = res.values('rec_time__date')
        res = res.annotate(energy=Max('total_energy'),
                           avg_pow=Avg('power'))
        return res
```

I want to obtain a daily summary with class method `daily_summary` as above.
but when I try it on `manage.py shell`, it give me error as below:

```
......meter/models.py in daily_average(date_rec)
     11     @classmethod
     12     def daily_average(date_rec=date.today()):
---> 13         res = EVC.objects.filter(rec_time__date=date_rec)
     14         res = res.values('rec_time__date')
     15         res = res.annotate(energy=Max('total_energy'),

....../django/db/models/manager.py in manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     80         def create_method(name, method):
     81             def manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
---> 82                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
     83             manager_method.__name__ = method.__name__
     84             manager_method.__doc__ = method.__doc__

....../django/db/models/query.py in filter(self, *args, **kwargs)
~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~
....../django/utils/dateparse.py in parse_date(value)
---> 75     match = date_re.match(value)
     76     if match:
     77         kw = {k: int(v) for k, v in match.groupdict().items()}

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@classmethod takes a class as the first argument so in your code it takes "date_rec" as class Meter.

To solve this issue either you need change `@classmethod` to `@staticmethod` decorator.
or you should write classmethod as follows:

```
@classmethod
def daily_summary(cls, date_rec=date.today()):
    function data goes here
```